# Animated cursor not working with anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, cursor

I've searched for hours but can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to adapt this codepen https://codepen.io/Nharox/pen/akgEQm to work with images and links but 2 things are not working. One is that the position of the cursor doesn't match vertically where the mouse pointer should be after scrolling with either the browser or the mouse wheel, and the other is that clicking the link has no effect. I can't seem to figure out why.

```
<body>
<div class="cursor hidden">
    <div class="cross">
        <div class="b b1"></div>
        <div class="b b2"></div>
    </div>
    <svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="52" height="52" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
        <path d="M1,26a25,25 0 1,0 50,0a25,25 0 1,0 -50,0"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Links

```
<div class="myrow">
    <div class="myrow__box">
        <a href="/link-to-page"><img alt="" src="/images/myimage.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.cursor {
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
opacity: 0;
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(.9) rotate(135deg);
transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
pointer-events: none;
&:before, &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
&:before {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
&:after {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
svg {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-dasharray: 160;
    stroke-dashoffset: 160;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
}
&-is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    &:before, &:after {
        width: 22px;
    }
    svg {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
}
.myrow {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
&__box {
    cursor: none; 
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(1);
    &:active {
        &:before {
            background-color: rgba(black, 0.15);
        }
    }
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgba(black, 0);
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
}
}
```

JS

```
(function showCursor() {
'use strict';
// Variables
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myrow__box'),
    cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor'),
    boxPos = [];
// Get coordinates for the current cursor position
function getPos(e, el) {
    var xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0;
    xPos = (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
    yPos = (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    var mouseX = e.clientX - xPos,
        mouseY = e.clientY - yPos; 
    cursor.style.top = '' + mouseY + 'px';
    cursor.style.left = '' + mouseX + 'px';
}
// Add event listeners and call fns for the corresponding box
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        var currentBox = this;
        boxPos = getPos(event, currentBox);
    }, false);
    boxes[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        this.appendChild(cursor);
         setTimeout(function() {
             cursor.classList.add('cursor-is-visible')
         }, 10);
    }, false);
    boxes[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        cursor.classList.remove('cursor-is-visible');
    }, false);
}
})();
```

I need the images to be 100% the size of the browser width at any size. The cursor is otherwise working properly and animating exactly as the codepen. Just no clickable link and wrong y position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the Y position is correct since you didn't register an event listener to update your Y position accordingly. So far you have only mouse - enter, move and leave events. To account for cursor position change that occurs due to scrolling (which is btw not a cursor event) you need to register a scoll event and update the cursor Y position value accordingly.

Secondly, the anchor doesn't do anything because it got lost as needle in the haystack. To make it work you can wrap your "box" element in anchor tag.

Here is the changed HTML:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="myrow">
        <div class="myrow__box">
            <img alt="" src="https://www.easyjet.com/en/holidays/shared/images/guides/austria/vienna.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here is the changed JS:

```
(function showCursor() {
'use strict';
// Variables
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myrow__box'),
    cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor'),
    boxPos = [],
    scrollY = 0;
// Get coordinates for the current cursor position
function getPos(e, el) {
    var xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0;
        xPos = (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
        yPos = (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    var mouseX = e.clientX - xPos,
        mouseY = e.clientY - yPos + scrollY; 
    cursor.style.top = '' + mouseY + 'px';
    cursor.style.left = '' + mouseX + 'px';
}
// Add event listeners and call fns for the corresponding box
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
boxes[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var currentBox = this;
    boxPos = getPos(event, currentBox);
}, false);
boxes[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    this.appendChild(cursor);
     setTimeout(function() {
         cursor.classList.add('cursor-is-visible')
     }, 10);
}, false);
boxes[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    cursor.classList.remove('cursor-is-visible');
}, false);
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if(event.target.scrollingElement.localName == "body") {
        scrollY = event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;          
    }
})     
})();
```

Check out the [pen](https://codepen.io/AndrewKiri/pen/YQEYmx) that I created for you to see the changes that I've made.

Comment: Please, make sure to mark an answer if it has solved your issue

Comment: Thank you. This is working perfectly in chrome, and IE, although the Y position doesn't update quite right in FireFox.

Comment: I'm not sure if this behavior in firefox is possible to fix after trying few approaches a while ago. The general approach to managing it with JavaScript I would say is bad because you manipulate the user's cursor position in an overly complex manner. I would suggest triggering animation on `:hover` css pseudo-state on wrapping anchors, that way the cursor and scrolling will be accounted for along with browser compatibility.